# How to show shadow around the linearlayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, roundedcorners-dropshadow

How can I show shadow for my linear layout. I want white colored rounded background with shadow around the linearlayout. I have done this so far.

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@xml/rounded_rect_shape"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<-- My buttons, textviews, Imageviews go here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

And rounded_rect_shape.xml under xml directory

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

   <corners
      android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
      android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
      android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a linearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no such attribute in Android, to show a shadow. But possible ways to do it are:

1. Add a plain LinearLayout with grey color, over which add your actual layout, with margin at bottom and right equal to 1 or 2 dp
2. Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout

Comment: 9-patch is the best way to do that!

Comment: Is there a way to use 9 patch with custom polygons? I tried this tool http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/ but it just creates shadows for oval/rectangle shapes

Answer (score 147):

There is also another solution to the problem by implementing a layer-list that will act as the background for the LinearLayoout.

Add background_with_shadow.xml file to `res/drawable`. Containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape 
            android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then add the the layer-list as background in your LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"/>
```

Comment: Woh! I made some of this and doesn't look so great. If you are looking for a holo standar, it's looks perfect. Thanks dude.

Comment: Nice effect, thanks!! But there one minor -imperceptible- issue I have: the shadow is not really next to the white layout, but share the centered space. If what I am saying is not clear enough, just try same code with 100dp in place of 1dp. 
I know, it's invisible in most cases but if someone can offer me a solution, that will be perfect !

Comment: @Poutrathor, interesting that you noticed that issue. Unfortunately I do not have another solution to offer at the moment.
What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Maybe someone can help you further with your problem.

Comment: "What is it that you are trying to accomplish?" Perfection, of course! 
Just kidding, I notice it, so I report it. your solution is really good for the trendy very short shadow and I am using it happily now. I wish I could give u more upvotes :)

Comment: can get a screenshot of what it is supposed to look like? I don't think I did it right because it looks broken

Comment: @user3453281, Can I ask you what kind of shadow you want to add to your linearlayout? Also in what way does it look broken?

Comment: To add, upper shape is shadow (!), while lower shape is the main larger part.

Comment: Can we set TOP shadow using approach similar to this one? @muthee

Comment: @inverted_index I do believe that you can use parameters android:right, android:left, android:bottom and android:top to adjust the shadow to your preferred location. (The example only used three of them)

Comment: @inverted_index here is a good example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436641/understanding-androids-layer-list

Answer (score 30):

Well, this is easy to achieve .

Just build a `GradientDrawable` that comes from black and goes to a transparent color, than use parent relationship to place your shape close to the View that you want to have a shadow, then you just have to give any values to height or width .

Here is an example, this file have to be created inside `res/drawable` , I name it as `shadow.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#9444"
        android:endColor="#0000"
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"> <!-- Change this value to have the correct shadow angle, must be multiple from 45 -->
    </gradient>

</shape>
```

Place the following code above from a `LinearLayout` , for example, set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `fill_parent` and `2.3dp`, you'll have a nice shadow effect on your `LinearLayout` .

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2.3dp"  
    android:layout_above="@+id/id_from_your_LinearLayout" 
    android:background="@drawable/shadow">
</View>
```

**Note 1:** If you increase `android:layout_height` more shadow will be shown .

**Note 2:** Use `android:layout_above="@+id/id_from_your_LinearLayout"` attribute if you are placing this code inside a RelativeLayout, otherwise ignore it.

Hope it help someone.

Comment: hello ... I know this is old ... but are you saying that the only way to get a shadow effect around the rectangular view structure is to create another rectangular structure, and then line them up accordingly??? ... thanks ... I am new in android ...

Comment: Hello @dsdsdsdsds I'm not sure if this is the only whay to get a shadow effect since material design introduced a lot of design resources, I'll take a look when I get home and I'll comment here if I find anything.

Answer (score 18):

For lollipop and above you can use [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).

For older versions:

Here is a lazy hack from:
http://odedhb.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-layout-shadow-without-9-patch.html

(toast_frame does not work on KitKat, shadow was removed from toasts)

just use:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
```

as a background

examples:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="I am a simple textview with a shadow"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
        />
```

and with different bg color:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
        android:padding="4dp"
        >
    <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button shadow"
            android:background="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: also `android:background="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"` for white

Answer (score 13):

Try this..   layout_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Apply to your layout like this

```
 android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but most of these answers require a ton of extra code.

If you have a light colored background, you can simply use this:

```
android:elevation="25dp"
```

Comment: It's not about having few lines of code, but your code should work in all the devices. The elevation you suggested will work only in API 21 and above

Answer (score 6):

Actually I agree with @odedbreiner but I put the dialog_frame inside the first layer and hide the black background under the white layer.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
        android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:top="5dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new XML by example named "shadow.xml" at DRAWABLE with the following code (you can modify it or find another better):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/middle_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="2dp"
          android:right="2dp"
          android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

After creating the XML in the LinearLayout or another Widget you want to create shade, you use the BACKGROUND property to see the efect. It would be something like :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_med"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. save this 9.png. (change name it to `9.png`)

[image]

2.save it in your `drawable`.

3.set it to your layout.

4.set padding.

For example :

```
<LinearLayout  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/shadow"
  android:paddingBottom="6dp"
  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
  android:paddingRight="5dp"
  android:paddingTop="6dp"
>

.
.
.
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following class for xml tag:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.FloatRange;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.webappmate.weeassure.R;

/**
 * Created by GIGAMOLE on 13.04.2016.
 */
public class ShadowLayout extends FrameLayout {

    // Default shadow values
    private final static float DEFAULT_SHADOW_RADIUS = 30.0F;
    private final static float DEFAULT_SHADOW_DISTANCE = 15.0F;
    private final static float DEFAULT_SHADOW_ANGLE = 45.0F;
    private final static int DEFAULT_SHADOW_COLOR = Color.DKGRAY;

    // Shadow bounds values
    private final static int MAX_ALPHA = 255;
    private final static float MAX_ANGLE = 360.0F;
    private final static float MIN_RADIUS = 0.1F;
    private final static float MIN_ANGLE = 0.0F;
    // Shadow paint
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
    };
    // Shadow bitmap and canvas
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
    // View bounds
    private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();
    // Check whether need to redraw shadow
    private boolean mInvalidateShadow = true;

    // Detect if shadow is visible
    private boolean mIsShadowed;

    // Shadow variables
    private int mShadowColor;
    private int mShadowAlpha;
    private float mShadowRadius;
    private float mShadowDistance;
    private float mShadowAngle;
    private float mShadowDx;
    private float mShadowDy;

    public ShadowLayout(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ShadowLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ShadowLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, mPaint);

        // Retrieve attributes from xml
        final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShadowLayout);

        try {
            setIsShadowed(typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.ShadowLayout_sl_shadowed, true));
            setShadowRadius(
                    typedArray.getDimension(
                            R.styleable.ShadowLayout_sl_shadow_radius, DEFAULT_SHADOW_RADIUS
                    )
            );
            setShadowDistance(
                    typedArray.getDimension(
                            R.styleable.ShadowLayout_sl_shadow_distance, DEFAULT_SHADOW_DISTANCE
                    )
            );
            setShadowAngle(
                    typedArray.getInteger(
                            R.styleable.ShadowLayout_sl_shadow_angle, (int) DEFAULT_SHADOW_ANGLE
                    )
            );
            setShadowColor(
                    typedArray.getColor(
                            R.styleable.ShadowLayout_sl_shadow_color, DEFAULT_SHADOW_COLOR
                    )
            );
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        // Clear shadow bitmap
        if (mBitmap != null) {
            mBitmap.recycle();
            mBitmap = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isShadowed() {
        return mIsShadowed;
    }

    public void setIsShadowed(final boolean isShadowed) {
        mIsShadowed = isShadowed;
        postInvalidate();
    }

    public float getShadowDistance() {
        return mShadowDistance;
    }

    public void setShadowDistance(final float shadowDistance) {
        mShadowDistance = shadowDistance;
        resetShadow();
    }

    public float getShadowAngle() {
        return mShadowAngle;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SupportAnnotationUsage")
    @FloatRange
    public void setShadowAngle(@FloatRange(from = MIN_ANGLE, to = MAX_ANGLE) final float shadowAngle) {
        mShadowAngle = Math.max(MIN_ANGLE, Math.min(shadowAngle, MAX_ANGLE));
        resetShadow();
    }

    public float getShadowRadius() {
        return mShadowRadius;
    }

    public void setShadowRadius(final float shadowRadius) {
        mShadowRadius = Math.max(MIN_RADIUS, shadowRadius);

        if (isInEditMode()) return;
        // Set blur filter to paint
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(mShadowRadius, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
        resetShadow();
    }

    public int getShadowColor() {
        return mShadowColor;
    }

    public void setShadowColor(final int shadowColor) {
        mShadowColor = shadowColor;
        mShadowAlpha = Color.alpha(shadowColor);

        resetShadow();
    }

    public float getShadowDx() {
        return mShadowDx;
    }

    public float getShadowDy() {
        return mShadowDy;
    }

    // Reset shadow layer
    private void resetShadow() {
        // Detect shadow axis offset
        mShadowDx = (float) ((mShadowDistance) * Math.cos(mShadowAngle / 180.0F * Math.PI));
        mShadowDy = (float) ((mShadowDistance) * Math.sin(mShadowAngle / 180.0F * Math.PI));

        // Set padding for shadow bitmap
        final int padding = (int) (mShadowDistance + mShadowRadius);
        setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        requestLayout();
    }

    private int adjustShadowAlpha(final boolean adjust) {
        return Color.argb(
                adjust ? MAX_ALPHA : mShadowAlpha,
                Color.red(mShadowColor),
                Color.green(mShadowColor),
                Color.blue(mShadowColor)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // Set ShadowLayout bounds
        mBounds.set(
                0, 0, MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        // Redraw shadow
        mInvalidateShadow = true;
        super.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        // If is not shadowed, skip
        if (mIsShadowed) {
            // If need to redraw shadow
            if (mInvalidateShadow) {
                // If bounds is zero
                if (mBounds.width() != 0 && mBounds.height() != 0) {
                    // Reset bitmap to bounds
                    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                            mBounds.width(), mBounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                    );
                    // Canvas reset
                    mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);

                    // We just redraw
                    mInvalidateShadow = false;
                    // Main feature of this lib. We create the local copy of all content, so now
                    // we can draw bitmap as a bottom layer of natural canvas.
                    // We draw shadow like blur effect on bitmap, cause of setShadowLayer() method of
                    // paint does`t draw shadow, it draw another copy of bitmap
                    super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);

                    // Get the alpha bounds of bitmap
                    final Bitmap extractedAlpha = mBitmap.extractAlpha();
                    // Clear past content content to draw shadow
                    mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

                    // Draw extracted alpha bounds of our local canvas
                    mPaint.setColor(adjustShadowAlpha(false));
                    mCanvas.drawBitmap(extractedAlpha, mShadowDx, mShadowDy, mPaint);

                    // Recycle and clear extracted alpha
                    extractedAlpha.recycle();
                } else {
                    // Create placeholder bitmap when size is zero and wait until new size coming up
                    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                }
            }

            // Reset alpha to draw child with full alpha
            mPaint.setColor(adjustShadowAlpha(true));
            // Draw shadow bitmap
            if (mCanvas != null && mBitmap != null && !mBitmap.isRecycled())
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, mPaint);
        }

        // Draw child`s
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    }


}
```

use Tag in xml like this:

```
<yourpackagename.ShadowLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:sl_shadow_color="#9e000000"
        app:sl_shadow_radius="4dp">
<child views>
</yourpackagename.ShadowLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

**put the below code in attrs.xml in resource>>values**

```
  <declare-styleable name="ShadowLayout">
    <attr name="sl_shadowed" format="boolean"/>
    <attr name="sl_shadow_distance" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="sl_shadow_angle" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="sl_shadow_radius" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="sl_shadow_color" format="color"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: It will provide shadow to any view,hope it will work for you

Comment: @CoolMind i have updated the code for R.styleable.ShadowLayout. Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for an update. I tried to test it on emulator of API 19 over `<TextView>`, it centered the TextView, but didn't add a shadow.

Comment: It works. I think sl_shadowed="true" is needed, radius is padding i.e. width of shadow, distance and angle makes dx,dy offset. What I think should be added is something like this 
// Set padding for shadow bitmap
        val padding = (shadowDistance + shadowRadius).toInt()
        setPadding( if(shadowLeft) padding else 0,
                    if(shadowTop) padding else 0,
                    if(shadowRight) padding else 0,
                    if(shadowBottom) padding else 0) Then you can conditionally turn on shadow on preferred edges of layout

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is  using nine patch image like this  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

OR

I have done this in the following way. This is my main layout in which round_corner.xml and drop_shadow.xml used as background resource. round_corner_two is same like round_corner.xml only the color attribute is different. copy the round_corner.xml,drop_shadow.xml and round_conere_two.xml into drawable folder.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/facebook_id"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shadow_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fb_butn_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

round_corner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<!-- view background color -->
<solid
    android:color="#ffffff" >
</solid>

<!-- view border color and width -->
<stroke
    android:width="0dp"
    android:color="#3b5998" >
</stroke>

<!-- If you want to add some padding -->
<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"    >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners
    android:radius="10dp"   >
</corners>

</shape>
```

drop_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is way too late. but i had the same requirement. i solved like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardElevation="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="3dp" >

<!-- put whatever you want -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

you need to add dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Answer (score -1):

set this xml drwable as your background;---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />-->Your shadow color<--

        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- White Top color -->
<item android:bottom="3px" android:left="3px" android:right="3px" android:top="3px">-->here you can customize the shadow size<---
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: This gives shadow to the text, not the layout.

Comment: No it will not show the shadow. Could you please provide a more detailed answer for how it works?