# Understanding Android's <layer-list>

Tags: android, xml-drawable, android-drawable, layer-list

I don't understand how the layer-lists work. I read the official [documentation with some examples](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) but it does not work for me like expected. I want four squares which should be padded with 1dp, but nothing is like expected. Here is a screenshot scaled by 500%:

[image: My suares]
<sup>(The wrong colors do not matter)</sup>
As you can see the size is completely wrong and the paddings are missing. I tried to set real values like width/height and right/left/top/buttom to be sure that android get the point what I want.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="9dp"
                android:height="9dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="5dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="3dp"
                android:height="3dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#f00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: How did you make the screenshot ? 'cause the image it gives me look absolutely correct...

Comment: I took the visual editor from eclipse.

Comment: @rekire The editor is buggy just so you know, it doesn't always display the proper shape. Always check on the device.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The values for left, top, right and bottom are measured from their respective edge.

So left=0dp, top=0dp, bottom=0dp & right=50dp will give you a rectangle that is (match_parent - 50dp) wide and not 50dp wide. Therefore larger values for "right" will actually give you a smaller rectangle.

The same would apply to the other value, but these would behave as expected in most cases, its just "right" that might cause confusion.

Comment: Its like padding in html, right=50dp adds a padding of 50dp to the right.

Answer (score 6):

Either you use `px` instead of `dp` or multiply all dimensions by `10`.

*I'm ashamed to admit that I don't exactly know WHY this is happening but my guess is that it has something to do with densities where `1dp` is a floating `px` value and the `ImageView` is scaled up.*

*Expert answer is welcomed :)*

Comment: You are right, but I would like to be dpi independed. Could you provide some more informations like if I really need all values of the rect (top,left,right,bottom) and an idea why dp seems not to be work in eclipse.

Comment: I just found this answer again finally I used px and used for other screensizes (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi) other values.