# Android - LayerList doesn't show some items

Tags: android, drawable, android-relativelayout, layer-list

I am using a LayerList that shows three items over each other:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_dialog_outer_stroke"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_dialog_middle_stroke"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/alert_dialog_inner_stroke"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:left="3dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

And the items are in three files:

Outer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#000000"></solid>
</shape>
```

Middle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#777574"></solid>
</shape>
```

Inner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#000000" />
    <solid android:color="#282830" />
</shape>
```

I am using an ImageView to show the LayerList:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/alert_dialog_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally...Nothing appears! If I comment the last item in layer list only the middle appears. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your drawables. All you are doing is placing those drawings (all the same size) on top of one another. Of course only the last thing added would be visible. you need to specify the sizes of the drawables. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436641/understanding-androids-layer-list).