# ImageView like border for another ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, image, xamarin, imageview

I want to insert dynamically an imageView inside another imageView.
One imageView is always fixed and I'd like to use it like border.
The second imageView is inserted dynamically inside the other and CENTER_INSIDE into it.

It is possible?

Comment: you can just create in xml and when u want to use it u can just set its visibility true else false

Comment: it is possible with <layer-list>. Please check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436641/understanding-androids-layer-list and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ImageView` over another `ImageView`. In your case follow these steps

1- Create an xml file `imageview_border.xml` and place it in `drawable` folder with such contents:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#dddddd"/>
</shape>
```

2- Now assign `android:background="@drawable/imageview_boder"`

3- Assign image to the `ImageView` using the `android:src` property like this:

```
android:src="@drawable/yourimage"
```

Comment: How can I insert an image even in the border?I need to do something like a postcard the outline of which is not only colorful , but it contains texts and images .

Comment: can you show an example of what you want to do in picture?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use 9 patch image:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

The Draw 9-patch tool is a WYSIWYG editor that allows you to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen. Selected parts of the image are scaled horizontally or vertically based indicators drawn within the image.