# How does <layer-list> in android works?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawable, layer-list

I have used the `<layer-list>` tag in android quite often to do various stuff like adding shadows and background to views, creating custom shapes, etc. Whatever I needed was always there some where on the internet. So I copied it and used it as it is.

But I want to know how `<layer-list>` actually works? How `<items>` are ordered to achieve the right shape or effect? I want to know so that every time when there is a need for some custom shape or effect I can do it by myself.

I consider `<layer-list>` a very powerful tool in android to create anything you want. I have done a decent amount of search on it since the time I am developing on android but I wasn't able to find any proper documentation or tutorial where there could be something like a step-by-step guide or explanation to create the shape or effect of your choice.

If someone can explain it to me then that would be great. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Android's <layer-list>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436641/understanding-androids-layer-list)

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I have gone through this question's answer already. But there also the answers are specific to just one figure as asked in the question. I want a general solutions/guide to all possible figures. Thus I don't consider it as duplicate of this question.

Comment: see [here](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java#70)

Comment: Have you ever considered to just [**look at the source code**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java#LayerDrawable)? If you want to know how it works then there is no better place to start.

Comment: I did but I wasn't able to understand that. @XaverKapeller