# how can I change LinearLayout's color with round corner in runtime?

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw LinearLayout with round corner.

I want changing this layout's color in runtime, using Colorfilter.
but ColorFilter can't apply layout, only apply view..

I don't know how can achieve this.

1. draw LinearLayout wiht round corner
2. and change layout's color in runtime

how can I do that?
I should be very grateful to you if you might help me :)
(Sorry for short English, because I'm foreigner :| )

Comment: You have to set background color with drawable in layout.

Comment: When i change layout's background or drawable, round corner was disappear.

Comment: Please check answer given by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to change the background color of linear layout with round corner dynamicaly right?

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setColor(Color.parseColor("Your color code"));
    gd.setCornerRadius(60);
    your_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take this example it shows how to apply a round corner and shadow using an xml drawable:
[Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a linearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

You can apply this background to your layout during runtime with

```
yourLayout.setBackgroundResource(int resid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code,

//this code in your activity, java file

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout_id);
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawable_file_in_xml);
```

//drawable_file_in_xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#444444" android:endColor="#202020" android:angle="-90"/>
    <corners android:radius="2dp"/> 
</shape>
```

In this code you can set round corner `<corners android:radius="2dp"/>`.

Comment: This code can't change layout's color and applying round corner same time. umm.. use setBackgroundResource() and  setBackgroundColor() for change layout's color, round corner was disappeared.

Comment: @user2549278 this code run fine in my application, please give 10dp  in corner so or major so you can get effect.

here i attached my code,

RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
  relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbutton);

Comment: round corner was run well. but change color after applying corner(use setBackgroundResource() and -> use setBackgroundColor()), corner was disappear.

Comment: please change color in xml and then set ones, if you fist set corner and then change color of linear layout then obvious it's remove corner.

So, please add your color in xml file and then set only setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loginbutton); it will work.