# CardView Corner Radius

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-cardview

Is there a way to make CardView only have corner radius at the top?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    >
```

Comment: In case if we just need to shape an image, use the material [ShapeableImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67851035/4694013) that draws the bitmap with the provided Shape.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Unless you try to extend the Android `CardView` class, you cannot customize that attribute from `XML`.

Nonetheless, there is a way of obtaining that effect.

Place a `CardView` inside another `CardView` and apply a transparent background to your outer `CardView` and remove its corner radius (`"cornerRadios = 0dp"`). Your inner `CardView` will have a cornerRadius value of 3dp, for example. Then apply a marginTop to your inner `CardView`, so its bottom bounds will be cut by the outer `CardView`. This way, the bottom corner radius of your inner `CardView` will be hidden.

The XML code is the following:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And the visual effect is the following:

[image: CardView with rounded corners only on top]

Always put your content in your Inner `CardView`. Your outer CardView serves only the purpose of "hiding" the bottom Rounded Corners of the inner `CardView`.

Comment: Note the shadow is incorrect (bottom corner shadows are still rounded), and the foreground selector would be more noticeably incorrect.

Comment: I think the easy way @shreedhar bhat described is better

Comment: Say, any idea what is the default value for cardCornerRadius? is it 4dp?

Comment: I'm not sure why everybody marked this as the answer. This is not the right answer. I tried this, but it's not working the way it should be.

Answer (score 72):

You can use the standard [`MaterialCard`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) included in the official [Material Components library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Use in your layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/MyCardView"
        ...>
```

In your style use the [**`shapeAppearanceOverlay`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) attribute to customize the shape (the default corner radius is `4dp`)

```
  <style name="MyCardView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut</item>
  </style>


  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

You can also use:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
     app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut"
     ...>
```

It is the result:

[image]

---

With **Jetpack compose** you can use the **`shape`** parameter in the Card.

Something like:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStart = 8.dp,
        topEnd = 8.dp,
        bottomEnd = 0.dp,
        bottomStart = 0.dp,
    )
){
    Text("Content Card")
}
```

Comment: this is not working with TabLayout. My corner tabs r not rounded. My requirement is only top corners of tabs should be rounded where bottom should remain sqare like. can you help me out in this?

Comment: If you're only applying this to a single component you can apply the shape appearance overlay directly in XML without needing a custom style.

`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut"`

Comment: This works well for me.

Comment: not working with bottomnavigation.

Comment: it doesn't work with `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`, when I set it removes all corners. But with `CardView` it works, it removes corners and still keeps the corners

Comment: now you have to use this 
'        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Material3.Corner.Top"
'

Answer (score 45):

```
dependencies: compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
```

---

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/Your_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </ImageView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Could you explain what does this block of code do? I can't seem to find any resources explaining about  the XML property `innerRadius`, `shape`, and `thicknessRatio`

Comment: Only  **`app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"`** will work too.

Answer (score 12):

There is an example how to achieve it, when the card is at the very bottom of the screen. If someone has this kind of problem just do something like that:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <SomeView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    </SomeView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Card View has a negative bottom margin. The view inside a Card View has the same, but positive bottom margin. This way rounded parts are hidden below the screen, but everything looks exactly the same, because the inner view has a counter margin.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this drawable xml and set as background to cardview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>

    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff000000"
        />

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        />

    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: This wont work with the cardView you need to take a Layout ie. Linear or Relative and set the background to it. then it will work.

Comment: but then what about the shadow effect?

Comment: For that you can use layer list. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout).

Comment: @SurenderKumar aree bhaii bhaii bhaaiii :D :D

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a drawable lib to custom round corner position, it looks like this:

[image: example.png]

You can get this lib at here:

https://github.com/mthli/Slice

Answer (score 5):

As @Gabriele Mariotti at feedback#2 suggested. Thanks so much @Gabriele bcz your feedback helped me on this case but my account can't vote for you at this time, so sorry :( (I also need helping like this topic creater)

I recommend to you shoud use `MaterialCardView` component (not CardView). Exactly is `MaterialCardView`.

So, this is the code in XML layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.CardView" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagePoke"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

And below is the code in style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay atribute:

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.CardView" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">30%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">30%</item>
</style>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I really wanna vote Useful these feedbacks that i saw in past when i'm learn to code. But, so sad is my account be limited by rules of SOF. So sad :(

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to make rounded corners is by using the CardCornerRadius attribute

```
app:cardCornerRadius="value"
```

simply write this in your XML code

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cv_info"
...
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
...>
```

and it will work perfectly
[image of the cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC5Ld.png)

the highest value you'll put in the rounded it will be.

but when we would like to make rounded corners only in certain spots like left bottom, right bottom and so on we will run into a problem, because the CardCornerRadius attribute does it to each side.
I managed to find a solution, not a perfect one, and sometimes this solution is irrelevant for example when you want to do it in the middle of the activity, it will work only if you want this to card view who's in the corners of the activity.
something like that [rounded corner image cardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sriAF.png)

so what I'm trying to achieve is to make the card view to overflow to activity [overflowed cardview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLrB1.png)

to do this you may set the width of the card view higher than the width of the phone or a better way is to set the width to match the parent and then set the margin to minus.
The XML code will be something like that

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-16dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-26dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="-16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-16dp"
```

and then set the app:cardCornerRadius to something high

```
app:cardCornerRadius="200dp"
```

and you should get the final result [final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiwdO.png)

you can also play with this and make some cool things with that!

I hope it will help someone in the future, I know it's not the most elegant solution or good solution at all but it should do the job, I tried some other things but it seems to be more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do 2 things :

1) Call `setPreventCornerOverlap(false)` on your CardView.

2) Put ***rounded*** Imageview inside CardView

About rounding your imageview, I had the same problem so I made a library that you can set ***different radii on each corner***. Finally I got the result what I wanted like below.

https://github.com/pungrue26/SelectableRoundedImageView

[image: Rounded ImageView inside CardView]

Comment: And that's how you turn your android app into ios :)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This here is a workaround if you want to achieve rounded corners at the bottom only and regular corners at the top. This will not work if you want to have different radius for all four corners of the cardview. You will have to use material cardview for it or use some third party library.

Here's what seemed to work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#F9F9F9">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvProfileHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="32dp">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"
            android:id="@+id/llProfileHeader"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <!--Enter your code here-->

        </LinearLayout>
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There's two cardview's in all. The second cardview is the one that will have rounded corners (on all sides as usual) and will hold all other subviews under it. The first cardview above it is also at the same level (of elevation), and has the same background but is only about half the height of the second cardview and has no rounded corners (just the usual sharp corners). This way I was able to achieve partially rounded corners on the bottom and normal corners on the top. But for all four sides, you may have to use the material cardview.

You could do the reverse of this to get rounded corners at the top and regular ones at the bottom, i.e. let the first cardview have rounded corners and the second cardview have regular corners.

Answer (score 1):

My custom way to implemented with a lib

//Rounded card

add this implementation on `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.captain-miao:optroundcardview:1.0.0'
```

in XML:

```
<com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:optRoundCardCornerRadius="40dp"
    app:optRoundCardLeftBottomCorner="false"
    app:optRoundCardRightBottomCorner="false"
    app:optRoundCardBackgroundColor="#E2EAF8">
```

Comment: It is not working(

Answer (score 0):

you can use the library:[OptionRoundCardview](https://github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview)

[image]

Comment: This doesnt show rounded corners... I Am using API >23

Comment: add enough margin space?

Comment: No the child views are match parent

Comment: Margin is there

Comment: this library not working with background-color app:optRoundCardBackgroundColor="@color/gray" it remove corner radius effects

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve it in Android Studio is explained below:

Step 1:
Write below line in dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

Step 2:
Copy below code in your xml file for integrating the `CardView`.

For `cardCornerRadius` to work, please be sure to include below line in parent layout:
`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

And remember to use `card_view` as namespace for using `cardCornerRadius` property.

For example : `card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"`

XML Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: He only wants it at the top.

Comment: Though, this is not an answer to this question, it helped me a lot, to find a mindblowing issue with namespaces ! :)

Comment: This is not the answer to the specific question but it has helped many users.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your ImageView inside a CardView, and add those properties to the ImageView:

```
android:cropToPadding="true"
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
```

That way you will get rid of the rounded bottom corner, but keep in mind that this comes in the price of having a small portion of your image cut off.

Answer (score 0):

You will find many ninja techniques on the internet but the best way to do this is to create a "Drawable Resource file" and design your own background and give a radius to every side or only one side.
So, these are the following steps:

1. Right-click on the Drawable file.

[image: Screenshot]

2. Then Click New and then click drawable resource file.

[image: Screenshot]

3. Then a page will popup you only need to set the name of your file.

[image: Screenshot]

4. Change the Selecter to Shape.

[image: Screenshot]

5. And add this code.

[image: Screenshot]

6. The final step is to set this newly created drawable file as the
   background.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to achieve this would be:

1.Make a custom background resource (like a rectangle shape) with rounded corners.

2.set this custom background using the command -

```
cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view2);
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_view_bg);
```

this worked for me.

The `XML` layout I made with top left and bottom right radius.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<corners android:topLeftRadius="18dp" android:bottomRightRadius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

In your case, you need to change only topLeftRadius as well as topRightRadius.

If you have a layout that overlaps with the corners of the card view and has a different color maybe, then you might need a different background resource file for the layout and in the xml set this background resource to your layout.

I tried and tested the above method. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -3):

If you're setting the card background programmatically, make use you use `cardView.setCardBackgroundColor()` and not `cardView.setBackgroundColor()` and make sure use using `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"` on the cardView.xml. That fixed it for me.

Btw, the above code (in quotations) is in Kotlin and not Java. Use the java equivalent if you're using Java.