# Buttons shape as well as selector tags

Tags: android, uibutton, shapes, states

I am trying to use shape selector tag nested with shape tag so that i make the corners of buttons round and also change the button states when focused/pressed. I have also used cardView widget with buttons in layout.xml. But corner shaping for buttons is not working. Here is the code given below for button_states.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/grey">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item><!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/orange">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@color/green">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:topRightRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Please help me out...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your button_bg.xml will as :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" 
android:state_pressed="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/rounded" />

<item android:state_focused="true" 
android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />

<item android:state_focused="false" 
android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded" />

</selector>
```

Then for rounded.xml corner.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
<solid android:color="#BABABA"/>
<corners android:radius="15px"/>
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
```

And if gradient.xml:

```
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>

   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
    <solid android:color="#BABABA"/>
    <corners android:radius="15px"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" /> 
   </shape>
   </item>
  <item>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="90" 
        android:startColor="#880f0f10" 
        android:centerColor="#880d0d0f" 
        android:endColor="#885d5d5e"/>

        <corners
            android:radius="15px" />
   </shape> 
 </item>
 </layer-list>
```

Assign the button_bg as background of the button in XML. It will give rounded corner and click effect both.

Comment: It's working thanks. But one more thing i want to ask that i am using cardView along with buttons which creates two layers and when i am creating the corner rounded buttons,there is some part of cardView is showing with its background color. I want that one also to be removed.

Comment: @AyushGupta check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius