# CardView with different corner radius

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-cardview, material-components-android

I have the following CardView and I want to set different radius for each corner in the card. Is it possible to change them by XML or programmaticaly? Thanks in advance.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT**
As Avinash suggest, I am looking for the behaviour of this lib [github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview](https://github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview) but using the default CardView item. If it is not possible to change it individually, this lib is a good approach.

Comment: In case if we just need to shape an image, use the material [ShapeableImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67851035/4694013) that draws the bitmap with the provided Shape.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

It requires the official [**`MaterialCardView`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialCardView.md) (which extends the [`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView)) and at least the version **1.1.0** of the [**Material components library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Add to your layout the `MaterialCardView`:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        style="@style/CustomCardViewStyle"
        ...>
      
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Define a custom style inheriting a [material card style](http://Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView) (for example `Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView`) and use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
  <style name="CustomCardViewStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
     <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners</item>
  </style>


  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay_card_custom_corners" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can also achieve it programmatically.
Just apply a custom [`ShapeAppearanceModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel) to the corners of the card.
Something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_corner_radius);
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(
  cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,..)
      .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,..)
      .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setBottomLeftCornerSize(0)
      .build());
```

**Note:** it requires the version 1.1.0 of the library.

---

With **Jetpack compose** you can use the **`shape`** parameter in the `Card`.

Something like:

```
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(
        topStart = 4.dp,
        topEnd = 8.dp,
        bottomEnd = 16.dp,
        bottomStart = 2.dp,
    )
){
    Text("Content Card")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gabriel, thanks for your answer. This example could be done without Android x?

Comment: @Juanje No, the new material components library requires [androidx](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#new-namespace-and-androidx)

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele, I will try then.

Comment: It's not working. "shapeAppearanceOverlay" is in red color

Comment: @VarunRaj It requires 1.1.0 (as described in the answer). Currently 1.1.0-alpha10

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti - if you could add the proper `implementation ..... alpha....` that would save people like me couple of minutes :)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, do you know a way to make the ImageView inside the MaterialCardView to respect the new rounded corners and fill the entire area ?

Comment: @KrzysztofKubicki There are some solutions. For example you can use the `ShapableImageView` in the material components library. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248890/imageview-with-only-one-rounded-corner/59430153#59430153).

Comment: Heads up, setShapeAppearanceModel w/ the builder didn't work for me when using unique corner sizes - they would always match one size. I had to create separate xml styles and set those at run time via 
            ShapeAppearanceModel.builder(
                context,
                style,
                0
            ).build()

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom xml and name it `rounded_corners.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="40dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"/>
<solid android:color="your_background_color" />
</shape>
```

And then use this as the background for your `CardView`:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that this may work for all other views other than `CardView`, so refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius) for seeing how to do a workaround.

Comment: You are right, this approach does not work for CardViews. I have already check the post you suggest but I think it is a dirty solution. I was loooking for something cleaner as modifying this attributes from code for example. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah I noticed that it is a workaround. There appears to not be a nice way of doing this.

Comment: it doesn't work for cardview, so this answer is no longer valid for this question.

Answer (score 2):

In case, if you use `ImageView` inside `CardView`, you should change `ImageView` into [`ShapeableImageView`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView.java). Normal `ImageView` only works with all corners not each corner.

Here is more detail [example](https://material.io/components/cards/android#theming-cards) on material.io docs

**themes.xml**

```xml
<style name="MyCardView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/MyCardViewOverlay</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCardViewOverlay">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <!-- below items does not work with normal ImageView -->
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">60dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**layout.xml**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/MyCardView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@color/orange_600"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/MyCardViewOverlay" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This here is a workaround if you want to achieve rounded corners at the bottom only and regular corners at the top. This will not work if you want to have different radius for all four corners of the cardview. You will have to use material cardview for it or use some third party library.

Here's what seemed to work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#F9F9F9">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvProfileHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="32dp">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_bg"
            android:id="@+id/llProfileHeader"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <!--Enter your code here-->

        </LinearLayout>
    
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There's two cardview's in all. The second cardview is the one that will have rounded corners (on all sides as usual) and will hold all other subviews under it. The first cardview above it is also at the same level (of elevation), and has the same background but is only about half the height of the second cardview and has no rounded corners (just the usual sharp corners). This way I was able to achieve partially rounded corners on the bottom and normal corners on the top. But for all four sides, you may have to use the material cardview.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can add it programmatically or by xml with following code.

```
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"// xml
cardView.setRadius(0);
```

this one is extra who is looking for elevation

```
app:cardElevation="0.7dp"//xml
app:cardMaxElevation="1dp"//xml
cardView.setCardElevation(2.1f);//code
cardView.setMaxCardElevation(3f);//code
```

The complete Java representation of the CardView’s XML.

```
CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardView);
cardView.setUseCompatPadding(true);
cardView.setContentPadding(30, 30, 30, 0);
cardView.setPreventCornerOverlap(true);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
cardView.setCardElevation(2.1f);
cardView.setRadius(0);
cardView.setMaxCardElevation(3f);
```

Comment: This solution sets all corners of the CardView, I want to set only one, topLeft for example.

Comment: okay got your point directly with cardview you can not achieve easily so i will suggest you to use some third party libs.
https://github.com/captain-miao/OptionRoundCardview
check this one

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have already check this project. It is my next step if I don't get any solution with CardView. Thanks! Appreciate your help!