# Rounded content below ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I was watching an Android Dev Summit video on Material Components recently (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPH3F0v1jB0) and I noticed they presented something cool with the example email app. Is there something built into Material components to achieve this rounded content below the action bar? The only way I know would be using shapes etc., but then it will cut into the content when scrolling.

[image]

Comment: It is called Backdrop: https://material.io/components/backdrop You need to implement it by Yourself or use one of libraries (You can find them easily on GitHub) because there is no official component.

Comment: Just use a container with rounded corners. For example a card view with only top [corners rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178933/cardview-with-different-corner-radius/57837141#57837141) or a LinearLayout with [rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178933/cardview-with-different-corner-radius/57837141#57837141).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OMIsie11 says the element in question is https://material.io/components/backdrop