# How to rotate an imageview and change the image on it while rotation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to create one rotate animation just similar to tick/cross animations where a moving tick gets converted into a cross and vice versa while rotating. The tick/cross animation is possible by using Vector graphics but how do i implement the same by using .png images on any imageview? I have gone through a lot of threads like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-check-tick-and-cross-animations-in-android/
but not getting any relevant one, so please help me out.

Code I am using to rotate the imageview:

```
 imageview.animate().rotation(360f).start()
```

Comment: How are you rotating the image, show us some code.

Comment: I am rotating an imageview

Comment: There must be a piece of code that does that, can you add it to the question

Comment: @VenomVendor just did please check