# How to change the upper corner radius of cardView in Android, which can work in latest version as well as pre lollipop?

Tags: android

How to change the upper corner radius cardView in Android, which can work in latest version as well as in pre lollipop version?

Comment: answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius

Answer (score 2):

Place a CardView inside another CardView and apply a transparent background to your outer CardView and remove its corner radius ("cornerRadios = 0dp"). Your inner CardView will have a cornerRadius value of 3dp, for example. Then apply a marginTop to your inner CardView, so its bottom bounds will be cut by the outer CardView. This way, the bottom corner radius of your inner CardView will be hidden.

The XML code is the following:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view_outer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```