# Rounded corners cardView don't work in RecyclerView - Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My android device is `4.3` and don't work round corner of `cardView` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/CardStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/BlackTrans"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imgbIcon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_serch" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And I write bellow code in my class but don't work yet :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    holder.CardStart.setCardElevation(0);
    holder.CardStart.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.BlackTrans));
    holder.CardStart.setRadius(5);
    holder.CardStart.setUseCompatPadding(true);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CardView Corner Radius](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius)

Comment: @ TWL.I read this link . it is not my response .

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It turns out that calling `View.setBackgroundColor(int)` on a `CardView` removes the rounded corners.

To change the background colour of a card and retain the corners, one needs to call `CardView.setCardBackgroundColor(int)` instead.

That may be the case for certain visitors to this post.

---

When subclassing `CardView`, I suggest adding the following method to protect your corners from accidental removal:

```
/**
 * Override prevents {@link View#setBackgroundColor(int)} being called,
 * which removes the rounded corners.
 */
@Override
public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int backgroundColor) {
    setCardBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}
```

In particular, I was working on a custom view implementation for React Native, and React was automatically applying a background colour to the view. This override solved that problem; it means other developers do not need to know the details of the underlying view.

Comment: this works, i applied the method to my code and worked as expected.

Comment: Very easy to make this mistake!

Comment: Thanks, man! Found this after pulling my hair for almost 30 mins.

Answer (score 6):

use this in topmost layout declaration in xml layout file:

`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this two attributes in your card view

```
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Here is the documentation for the first attribute (which contains reference to the second)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean)

This should do the trick