# Strange transparent CardView bg

Tags: java, android, cardview

I have a problem with transparent CardView. It happens when i set CornerRadius attribute to card, without this attribute everything is ok. It looks like this(marked red):[image]

Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/some_dimen_here"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">
```

How it cane be fixed? any ideas?

Comment: If the blank box is a TextView, then just change your textColor of the textView.

Comment: @AslamHossin and it will remove this strange lines on sides(marked red) don't think so. I try to remove all content from this card view, and it doesn't help at all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please remove the card_view:cardBackgroundColor  and try

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: as i mentioned in question, problem is disappeared when i remove corner radius, but i actually need it((

Comment: what is value for your @dimen/some_dimen_here ?

Comment: in this case 0dp. But this dimen can store any value. in case when it f.e. 4dp the same problem. But when we just didn't add it, everything ok.