# Different corner radius values for a MaterialCardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, material-components, material-components-android

Is is possible to have different values for each corner radius of a MaterialCardView? And if so how?

I tried something like the code below but it doesn't seem to have any effect

```
    float radius = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
    ShapePathModel leftShapePathModel = new ShapePathModel();
    leftShapePathModel.setTopLeftCorner(new RoundedCornerTreatment(radius));
    leftShapePathModel.setTopRightCorner(new RoundedCornerTreatment(radius));
    MaterialShapeDrawable bg = new MaterialShapeDrawable(leftShapePathModel);
    container.setBackground(bg);
```

where container is

```
@BindView(R.id.container) MaterialCardView container;
```

Comment: instead of posting the link, post relative code that you have tried.

Comment: Done, sorry! :)

Comment: First, always post your code in a question. Second, have you checked all the solutions on Stackoverflow? Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius

Comment: I've seen that post however I was hoping there's a better solution than nesting two cardviews. I found this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117662587 which seems to address my problem but I'm not too sure how to make use of it and I've not found much documentation around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial solution was correct but it was missing one line:

```
float radius = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);
ShapePathModel leftShapePathModel = new ShapePathModel();
leftShapePathModel.setTopLeftCorner(new RoundedCornerTreatment(radius));
leftShapePathModel.setTopRightCorner(new RoundedCornerTreatment(radius));
MaterialShapeDrawable bg = new MaterialShapeDrawable(leftShapePathModel);
container.setBackground(bg);
```

If you add

```
container.invalidate()
```

as suggested by Cameron above it seems to work.

Comment: this does not crop content, so rectangular content flows outside on these corners

Answer (score 22):

You can use a **custom style** and the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

```
  <style name="MyCardView" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut</item>
  </style>


  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

or you can apply a custom [**`ShapeAppearanceModel`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel) to the corner of the card using something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_corner_radius);
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(
  cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
      .toBuilder()
      .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
      .setBottomRightCornerSize(0)
      .setBottomLeftCornerSize(0)
      .build());
```

[image]

Comment: Shows rounded corners on android studio but on the device, it's all rectangular!

Comment: @VarunRaj are you using 1.1.0-alpha10 ? Just tried and both with ShapeAppearanceModel and shapeAppearanceOverlay with the values in the example on Android P/Q the result is the same screenshot attached in the answer.

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'` line from straight from the app. Will work on only P and Q?

Comment: I just saw it from very close the rounded corners are there but only visible when dragging my bottom sheet.

Comment: Are you trying to have a bottomSheet with round corners?

Comment: Yep! But I want shadows as well so I thought CardView will be easy and perfect for the job.

Comment: @VarunRaj You can also have roundCorners in the bottomSheet with the same `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute without using a card. You can also have the elevation using `<item name="android:elevation" ns2:ignore="NewApi">xxdp</item>` in the style. For the persistent BottomSheet you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626774/2016562), for the modal [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627229/2016562).

Comment: this does not crop content, so rectangular content flows outside on these corners

Comment: custom ShapeAppearanceModel solution worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Try This Also

```
     <style name="TopCornerCardview" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">@dimen/dp25</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">@dimen/dp25</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
        <item name="contentPadding">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            style="@style/TopCornerCardview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TopCornerCardview"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

>
<!--views here-->
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to call `ShapeAppearanceModel shape = ((MaterialShapeDrawable)container.getBackground()).getShapeAppearanceModel()` on your `MaterialCardView`. From there you could call `setTopLeftCorner()` or the other methods to set corner treatments with different values. You may need to call `container.invalidate()` after you set the corners.

Comment: Thanks for that but unfortunately the background returned by the MatericalCardView cannot be cast to MaterialShapeDrawable. However, invalidating the container using the code I posted initially seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I think it might use a LayerDrawable to wrap it with other things. Unfortunately for now it looks like it's not that easy to get access to. We're working to make it easier for each component.