# Round Corners using CardView and ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to round the corners of an ImageView in android xml development. I use a parent of CardView with CornerRadius and I made sure the API is above 19 to be able to use the elevation feature. For the moment I don't want to use any 3rd party, even though I tried and that didn't work either for unknown reasons.

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/profilecardview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profpic" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thank for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CardView Corner Radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342633/cardview-corner-radius)

Comment: No it is not the same, because I am trying without any 3rd party and this is exactly what they are doing and it still does not work