# How to add a drop shadow to a Rectangular Shape in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, shadow, dropshadow, roundedcorners-dropshadow

I am developing an Android App in which I need to use a Rectangular shape which should have a drop_shadow. I have designed a rectangular shape but somehow i am not able to add a drop shadow to it on (right and left sides).
P.S.: this rectangular shape is added as a background attribute.

If this type of Question is already been answered then please provide the links here.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!!

[image]

Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)