# Android Bottom Navigation Bar with drop shadow

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-bottomnav

I'm implementing [Bottom Navigation Bar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-style) in Android app using [Google's support design library v25.1.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html). Is there any way to add drop shadow effect, same as current Android native Google Photos app?

[image]

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can draw your own shadow just above the bottom bar using simple View and its background:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>
```

drawable/shadow.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#1F000000"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Also, there are no compatibility issues if use this approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can use elevation to add shadows to any view

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myview"
...
android:elevation="2dp"

android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

Refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html) for more information

Comment: Does not work in my project: "Attribute 'elevation' is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 16)", would used that if it did work.

Answer (score 5):

For those using a CoordinatorLayout with the Bottom Navigation Bar (or `BottomAppBar`), you can use the following to attach a shadow above the bar:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>
```

Obviously, replace the `@+id/toolbar` with the id of the Bottom Navigation Bar

Answer (score 3):

For those using Material Component - this has been fixed by `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09`.

Available since 1.1.0-alpha05 : https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha05

Use `android:elevation="4dp"` to set elevation shadow.

Also, do not forget to set `clipChildren="false"` on your main layout, otherwise, the shadow will be overwritten.

Comment: Any documentation link?

Comment: It did not work out