# How to create shadow effects just like shown below for linear layout in android?

Tags: android, shadow

I was wondering if it's possible to create shadow effect for linear layout in android just like shown below.
Any help would be appreciated...

[image]

Comment: Is setting `android:elevation` did not work for you?

Comment: But that is going to work only if the android version is 21 and above. Is there any way that I can add the same design in lower version?

Comment: If you really want a shadow effect. you can use a `CardView` with `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` May I know the reason why you want to use `LinearLayout` in particular?

Comment: make `CardView` as parent of `LinearLayout` which you are mentioning.

Comment: @SamuelRobert hey have tried it using 9-patch it will be a better solution there are others also i have mentioned those in my answer

Comment: @SamuelRobert see my Updated answer it's work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then Use 9 Patch image for that,

[9 patch image](http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/)

for more detail here is question for [shadow LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

Comment: I've already tried the above code. Apparently, the above code adds just a border to my Linear Layout. What I really wanted was the blending shadow effect just like I've shown in the image.

Comment: @SamuelRobert see my update answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Nonetheless, elevation property would work only if the sdk level is 21 and above. I was trying to accomplish this effect from api level 11 onwards.

Comment: @SamuelRobert See the edit.

Comment: Buddy, The updated answer just adds a border below the linear layout. What I really need is the fading shadow effect not a border at the bottom.

Comment: go to the 9 patch image link.

Comment: Ya. you got the answer to my question. one more thing though, can we do this just with an xml drawable file?. or 9-patch is the best choice?

Comment: you are using api level 11 so it is difficult to make drawable xml of your shape shadow better use 9 patch image for that.

Answer (score 5):

**There are lots of ways and here they are Use that which one suits you**

> **Create your own drawable**

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and **your_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:background="@drawable/border"
  >
</LinearLayout>
```

> **You can also use use a drawable from android**

```
android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_frame"
```

or:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```

> **Use a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout**

Use this website to create 9 patch with shadow

http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Comment: Hey, man, how could i smooth more the border shadow color on your code?