# Creating shadows to appbar layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a app in which I need to drop shadow in app bar layout like this

[image]

but instead of that I am getting this:

[image]

Here is my code which I used

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="32dp"
    android:outlineProvider="bounds"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:autofillHints="no"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/search_text_hint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#DBFFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#D44A4A4B" />
    </Toolbar>


</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984949/how-to-create-shadow-effects-just-like-shown-below-for-linear-layout-in-android

Comment: @Mr.Patel Sorry but this is not helping

Answer (score 0):

In your code instead of `android:elevation="32dp"` use `app:elevation="32dp"`.

Comment: Actually AppBarLayout has app:elevation attribute but somehow it ain't working maybe removed

Comment: Try this `app:elevation="32dp"` on toolbar also.

Comment: or you can try adding elevation to appbar programmatically.