# Android: Border for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, border, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` and I want to put a border for it . It should look like below.

[image]

This is my layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".activities.AddInfoMainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_img01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample01" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_txtView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/add_info_txt_one_01"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_img02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample02" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_txtView02"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:text="@string/add_info_txt_one_02"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Util to now I haven't use any style for my layout.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: What have you tried? `android:elevation`? A nine-patch background image? Something else?

Comment: You have to use card view  as parent and in that you have to use linear layout with image and text.set elevation as you want in cardview property

Comment: Wrap up your LinearLayout with a `CardView` widget instead.

Comment: didn't see your efforts !! anyway ,refer recycle view ,that used with card view .that is the exactly gives same UI as you want.

Comment: you can also create a shape for drawable and set it as your `android:background` for the layout

Comment: you just need grid view with custom adapter. and set layout in adapter which i was posted

Comment: I found an answer for the problem. Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095309/4924272 and I take it from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set border you can create an xml file in your drawable with the below code.

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
        <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@android:color/white" />   
</shape>
```

and from your linearlayout set your background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com....
    android:background="@drawable/border"> 

    <!--- code here --->

</LinearLayout>
```

but base on your image you are looking for `cardView`. Try to search for `cardview`.

click this [link](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/) for example and tutorial for cardview.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_3sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_img01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/sample01" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_info_layout_one_txtView01"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/add_info_txt_one_01"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use card view if you  want shadow effect . Add card elevation property `card_view:cardElevation="4dp"` set dp as much as you want.

Or add this drawable file in your `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:centerX="35%"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="linear"/>

    <size
        android:width="80dp"
        android:height="80dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#eaeaea"/>
</shape>
```