# I want to add shadow only on the left and right corners

Tags: android, listview, shadow

I have tried shadowing the list view i can make all the four sides.. but what i need here to shadow only the left and right corners of the list view like one in the given below image:

[image]

Comment: use 9 patch image

Comment: what is the use of 9 patch image? am sorry am not aware of it.. suggest me what you know and let me also browse..

Comment: i just browsed what is 9 patch image.. i think it won't work out for me since am want this shadow effect in my dynamically generated list view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31722183/3303075 TAke a look at this example

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a covering way.The foreground layer is covered on the background layer and sets the padding of the foreground layer to expose the background layer only to the gradient edge.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
    <!-- layout background -->  
    <item>  
        <!-- show rectangle area -->  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >  
            <gradient  
                android:angle="270"  
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF"  
                android:centerColor="#000000"  
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"/>  
        </shape>  
    </item>  
    <!-- layout foreground -->  
    <item  
        android:bottom="5px"  
        android:top="5px">  
        <!-- show rectangle area -->  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >  
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />  
        </shape>  
    </item>  
</layer-list>
```

You can also use `Layer-List`specific reference SDK doc

Comment: Hey thanks for your xml @LittleMice i got what i want.. and thanks all for your help..!!

Comment: Can help you very happy

Answer (score 0):

I Would suggest you create a drawable as per your requirement and add it to the bottom of the view.

Comment: Its kind of like a hack. But It Worked for me. when i wanted use a shadow effect in tabs