# How add shadow in bottom of my linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I want add shadow to my Bottom of linear layout.

Basically, this linear layout is an custom header bar of my layout.

it contains the title of my layout and the icon. and I want to add the shadow to the bottom of the layout. can someone help me.

Comment: Can you show your xml file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680067/7835745 , this might help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add shadow to linear layout - android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478246/how-to-add-shadow-to-linear-layout-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Cardview and gve elevation to it.
    It will give you Shadow effect.

```
 `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin4"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin8"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin4"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoomImageview"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```