# Unaffected drop shadow in android

Tags: java, android, view, shadow, dropshadow

I want to draw drop shadow effect under a view but the following views move down.

I tried only background drawable and that doesn't fix my problem.

How to draw drop shadow so that it does not affect neighboring views?

**In my case i have this result with code**

> mPinnedHeaderView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow);
>   [image]

**But i need this:**

[image]

Comment: try using `cardview` with `compactpadding = true`

Comment: Can you elaborate more what are you trying to do.. add some code, we cannot solve your problem for you. You should try first to solve your issues and if you get stuck we can help you out

Comment: Improved question clarity and fixed spelling

Comment: @Darko added screenshots for example

Comment: @АлексейВишняков maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout