# Android, display a shadow under each items of a RecyclerView (without margin-padding)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shadow, android-flexboxlayout

I'm trying to display a **shadow** under items of a RecyclerView but there is **no space** between items.

I'm trying to reproduce something like that :

[image: Design for an UI]

I've implemented a RecyclerView and a FlexboxLayout so items takes the whole place in the screen.

Here is the recycler view declaration:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:listitem="@layout/category_item"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
```

Here is the item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/itemContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:justifyContent="center"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

And the `onBindViewHolder` method from the adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (categories != null) {
        Category category = categories.get(position);
        holder.itemTitle.setText("Lorem ipsum");
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = holder.itemContainer.getLayoutParams();

        holder.itemContainer.setBackgroundResource(category.getColor());

        if (lp instanceof FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) {
            FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams flexboxLp =
                    (FlexboxLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemContainer.getLayoutParams();
            flexboxLp.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what i get:

[image: My Application Design]

As you can see, i put a padding so we can see the shadow behind but since there is no space between items, the shadow isn't displayed.
I'd like the **shadow** to be displayed on **top** of other items.

I don't know how to make a good looking separation between items otherwise, i've tried with `DividerItemDecoration` but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35406689/9434800

I've created a gradient resource:

```
<shape xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@color/c1"
        android:centerY="90%"
        android:endColor="@color/c1_darker"
        android:startColor="@color/c1"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

And i set it as background of my item, this way the top of my items are darker and it seems like it's the shadow of items above them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the custom layout of an adapter. Into the custom layout at the bottom, you can give your border or shadow. It will work for you.

Comment: I've tried and i didn't get the desired effect, i got a darker line at the bottom but there is no fade effect, so it doesn't look like a shadow