# How to set shadow to line?

Tags: android, shadow

I do not know how to do it

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#698cc8"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/npZm0.png

Comment: Have you tried this answer from user Hariharan? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24095309/3186095

Comment: I have tried but it did not work

Comment: A simple shadow on the view can be achieve by setting `android:elevation` to the view.

Comment: Use layerlist to achieve this

Comment: Thanks guys. I have sovled it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help you,

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="8dp"
                android:color="#c7c7c7"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#698cc8"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

out put is,

[image]

give needed shade color in first item. then give `bottom` value in second item.
which means second item height get reduce from bottom corresponding to bottom value.there for we can visible shade color below the line.