# How to create a shadow for a layout or ImageView?

Tags: android, material-design, shadow

i am trying to coding the below image for android app design, i can not get shadow as same as image how i can do it perfectly? and can control with opacity, degree and color of shadow?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a linearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android LinearLayout : Add border with shadow around a linearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cardView which has an elevation attribute which gives shadows to your card view.

also there are third party libraries which you can use like this:

https://github.com/loopeer/shadow

also here is Google documentation which describes how you should use shadows in your ui:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping