# Android create very blured shadow for button

Tags: android, button, shadow

I need to create very blurred and long shadow for button. Any suggestion how to reach effect like on photo in android?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html), but it's quite limited to the new API's.

Then there is [drawables and gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356060/how-to-add-shadow-effect-on-drawable-in-android).

Last but not least I'd say that creating graphics in image manipulation application, e.g. Phtotoshop, is a way to go.