# Shadow to Linear layout in android

Tags: android

[image]

hello,
This is my UI, i am trying to put shadow to Linear Layout, if you see there is shadow background of Linear layout, 
I have tried, took parent layout gave to it grey color and then gave white color to this linear layout, but it looks grey border, but as you see i don't want that way. This is shadow 
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095223/android-linearlayout-add-border-with-shadow-around-a-linearlayout

Comment: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android) look at archie.bpgc answer

Comment: @RohitSharma thank you, i have created 9-patch-image, it looks the same as i want :)

Answer (score 3):

Give some elevation to your linear layout like

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Put this in your xml

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `CardView`?

You can wrap your `LinearLayout` in `CardView` and get the shadow effect from the `CardView`. As far as I think, this is not possible with simple XML and you will have to use [9-Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html). Since you want this compatible with pre-lollipop, `CardView` is the simplest way.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" />
```